# Google tag manager causes javascript errors on wordpress site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-tag-manager

When i tried to add to add GTM code on my wordpress site i get javascript errors when i'm loggen in. If i view site like simple user everything works ok. Javascript errors that i get in console are like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).owlCarousel is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: t(...).ajaxsearchlite is not a function
```

GTM code is added inside head tag (moving it to the footer doesn't help). Noscript code part is also added after body tag. Javascript files on my site is connected as it should be, i mean via wp_enqueue_script function and loaded after jQuery.
Any thought what could causes this problems? As i understand when i'm logged in on site wordpress connect additional scripts/files which could have conflict with GTM code?

Answer (score 1):

So problem was with Query Monitor plugin. For some reason GTM code has conflict with this plugin code. Maybe it would help somebody who would have similar problems